# No proxy tunnel softwares works properly on my OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, tunnel, socks

I run PoroxyCap 2.7 on my OSX and it used to work properly 38 days ago, then expired, so I bought a licence number, and the software now opens.However it doesn't redirect through proxy.Before buying it's been set up with SOCKS5 type, hostname 192.168.25.4, port 8080, and username + password. Also created a rule to enable the checkbox for 'redirect through proxy' , 'resolve names remotely' and 'transport TCP' .   Same settings i'v been trying so far, and unfortunately doesn't work. When I open the tab 'Status and Logs' it doesn't show neither connections nor SSH Tunnels, just Error Logs.
Also tried other softwares like MacProxy, Proxyfier, YourFreedom, TunnelBlick.. nothing works.

Really need to proxy my browser(safari or chrome)

would be much appreciated ur help!